# .addFile seems to be deprecated, what other method can I use?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I want to make a copy of a file from Google Drive to the destination I set it to but .addFile seems to be deprecated. I tried using `moveTo` and `makeCopy` but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is the code I have for now:

```
function copyfile() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet_Patients");
var activeSheetFM = ss.getSheetByName("_FolderMaker_");
var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
var data = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,3,1,1).getValue();
var secondData = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,4,1,1).getValue();
var folder_Name = [data+ ", " +secondData];

var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_Name);
while (folders.hasNext()) {
      const folder = folders.next();
      var id = folder.getId(); 
} 
activeSheetFM.getRange(2,4,1,1).setValue(id);
  
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1g25_24OTv_t5Qav2Q1hwEM_YBiPSaWWb");
var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1pqh74miSSy9WDSD3kpi02kkI6XDuXiuU");
var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(id);
//Logger.log(finalId);


var finalFile = file.makeCopy(data+ ', '+ secondData + ' ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' ' + file.getName());
dest_folder.addFile(finalFile);
source_folder.removeFile(finalFile);
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#moveTo(Folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `dest_folder` of `var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(id);` is FolderIterator.

  - I thought that this might be the reason of your issue about `I tried using moveTo and makeCopy but i cant seem to get it to work.`.
- In your situation, if the folder retrieved with `var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_Name);` is the destination folder, you can directly use `const folder = folders.next();`.
- In the current stage, I would like to propose to use `moveTo` for movinf the file to the specific folder.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_Name);
while (folders.hasNext()) {
      const folder = folders.next();
      var id = folder.getId(); 
} 
activeSheetFM.getRange(2,4,1,1).setValue(id);
  
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1g25_24OTv_t5Qav2Q1hwEM_YBiPSaWWb");
var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1pqh74miSSy9WDSD3kpi02kkI6XDuXiuU");
var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(id);
//Logger.log(finalId);


var finalFile = file.makeCopy(data+ ', '+ secondData + ' ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' ' + file.getName());
dest_folder.addFile(finalFile);
source_folder.removeFile(finalFile);
```

To:

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_Name);
var dest_folder;
if (folders.hasNext()) {
  dest_folder = folders.next();
} else {
  throw new Error("No folder.")
}
activeSheetFM.getRange(2,4,1,1).setValue(dest_folder.getId());
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1g25_24OTv_t5Qav2Q1hwEM_YBiPSaWWb");
var finalFile = file.makeCopy(data+ ', '+ secondData + ' ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' ' + file.getName());
finalFile.moveTo(dest_folder);
```

#### References:

- [getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename)
- [moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

You basically need to use [makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination) where destination needs to be of a type `folder` and not an `iterator`.

Therefore, you should do:

```
var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
var finalFile = file.makeCopy(data+ ', '+ secondData + ' ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' ' + file.getName(),dest_folder);
```

---

### Solution:

```
function copyfile() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet_Patients");
var activeSheetFM = ss.getSheetByName("_FolderMaker_");
var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
var data = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,3,1,1).getValue();
var secondData = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,4,1,1).getValue();
var folder_Name = [data+ ", " +secondData];

var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_Name);
while (folders.hasNext()) {
      const folder = folders.next();
      var id = folder.getId(); 
} 

activeSheetFM.getRange(2,4,1,1).setValue(id);
  
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1g25_24OTv_t5Qav2Q1hwEM_YBiPSaWWb");
var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1pqh74miSSy9WDSD3kpi02kkI6XDuXiuU");
var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  
var finalFile = file.makeCopy(data+ ', '+ secondData + ' ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' ' + file.getName(),dest_folder);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be another method that works, Thanks as usual for helping me improve. cheers