# why does a function have strike through in the text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, ide, strikethrough

the addFile part is shown with strikethrough text. not sure why. is seems to be working. should I change something? looks like this [image: addfile with strikethrough]

been using this for a few years. moves recording for my class to their respective folders by the prefix on the file name. works great not sure why this kind of functionality is not built in yet.

```
function MoveRecordingsToFolders()
{
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderid_is_placed_here'); // folder where recordinds are dumpped about 73 long 
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    file = files.next();
    if (file.getName().indexOf("CAD242 #")== 0)
    {
      DriveApp.getFolderById('folderid_of_destination').addFile(file); //
      file
        .getParents()
        .next()
        .removeFile(file);
    }
  }
}
```

there are no issues yet just wonder if there will be.

Comment: addfile is deprecated [Deprecated Methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#deprecated-methods_1)

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script, web editor / IDE, uses the strike-through style on deprecated methods. In this case, `Folder.addFile` is deprecated.

This was announced in the blog post, [Simplifying Google Drive’s folder structure and sharing models](https://workspace.google.com/blog/product-announcements/simplifying-google-drives-folder-structure-and-sharing-models) and on the release note dated [July
27, 2020](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/docs/release-notes#July_27_2020), and it's included in the section of deprecated methods on the [Folder class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder) page.

Deprecated methods might still work for a while, but they might stop working suddenly, so it's better to refactor your script to avoid using these methods.

Related

- [.addFile seems to be deprecated, what other method can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64546769/1595451)